# Discord.py: How to get access to self in a check's predicate function?

Tags: python, discord.py, python-decorators

I've spent at least a day trying to find an answer to the question, including messing around with nested decorators for at least a couple hours but I don't seem to be able to figure it out.

I am using Discord.py and it's `commands.check` "decorator generator", but I think the problem (and likely it's solution) might not be really Discord.py specific.

The problem statement is as follows:

I would like to declare a Discord.py `check` on a `Cog`, but need access to the Cog's instance to do some data fetching to resolve the check.

Now, Discord.py's syntax for declaring a check is to call the commands.check function given a predicate function, which in turn returns a decorator that can be applied to any of the Cog's methods, like

```
def custom_check():
  async def predicate(ctx):
    # I'll need to do some data fetching here...
    return True
  return commands.check(predicate)

class MyCog(commands.Cog):
  @commands.command()
  @custom_check()
  async func(self, ctx):
    pass

  async def some_data_fetching():
    pass
```

I've been trying to figure out how to be able to solve this, but can't wrap my head around it. I've been exploring how to create a wrapping closure that has access to self, but

1. I can't get it to work ('predicate called' never prints) and
2. I still can't figure out how to inject self into the `predicate` function -- `commands.check` needs to be called (and predicate passed into it) before any method would be getting invoked and self could become available.

```
def custom_check():
    async def predicate(ctx):
        print('predicate called')
        return False

    check_decorator = commands.check(predicate)

    def custom_decorator(f):
        async def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return await f(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    return lambda f: check_decorator(custom_decorator(f))
```

Any help or advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've figured out why my predicate wasn't being called. I incorrectly applied the decorator to the `some_data_fetching` method, instead of to the `func` command. Applying it to the correct method makes my second example behave like I would expect. I still don't know how to get access to `self` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**: Use `ctx.cog` or `ctx.args`

```
def custom_check():
  async def predicate(ctx):
    data = await ctx.cog.some_data_fetching()
    return data.checks_out
  return commands.check(predicate)
```

I decided to take a closer look at the provided Context (`ctx`) and realized that it has both an args attribute (that has the arguments passed to the command invocation, including `self`) as well as a `cog` attribute that references the cog that the invoked command lives on. Either one of them will allow me to do what I need to.

Thanks for having been my audience.